# Blazor WASM does not debug on Rider

Tags: c#, google-chrome, debugging, blazor, webassembly

about my system:
I use Linux with Rider and Brave as browser.

I can start the application without any problems but unfortunately I can't debug it because I get the error "DEBUGGING IS NOT ENABLED", how do I fix this?

[image: Debugging image]

Comment: I found out, that the problem is Brave.
I need to use the Rider EAP version and Chrome (I will test it with blank chromium).
Does anyone know why debugging is disabled in Brave, and how to turn it on?

Comment: I'm not directly certain if this has to do with Brave or Blazor WASM in general. I've been using Blazor WASM a lot, and always had a lot of debugging issues while using Rider. JetBrains is working a lot on it, and if you read the patch notes you see a lot of improvements and bug fixes being mentioned for it. Blazor Server in comparison works a lot better with Rider. Chromium might work better, you should definitely give that a try. See [Blazor WebAssembly Client-Side Debugging](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-45261/Blazor-WebAssembly-Client-Side-Debugging)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the privacy settings in Brave limit a lot of functionality regarding Blazor WASM, one of them seems to be the debugger and it can't attach to the session correctly.

I'm also running Rider on Linux (Fedora 37) and can debug just fine with Firefox, but on Brave the debugger can't attach. Unfortunately I don't seem to find any insights on what exact setting in Brave is blocking the debugger hook.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you were able to get Firefox debugging working? I always end up getting "Unable to attach Blazor debugger: compatible browser not found"